# Update data in Kartik Detailview didn't work

Tags: yii2, updates, edit, detailview, kartik-v

I've detail showed using Kartik Detail View. This widget has **Edit** inline function by clicking pencil icon button in top right side like this
[image]

And then the table will be editable like this:
[image]
I've edit the data, and then click the Floopy Disk Icon button as Save.

And nothing happen, my data still the same, my update not success.

**This is my code in view.php**

```
<?=
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'condensed' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'mode' => DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
    'panel' => [
        'heading' => 'Data Details',
        'type' => DetailView::TYPE_INFO,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'product',
        'productId',
        'distDate',
        'created_at',
        'created_by',
        [
            'attribute' => 'is_exported',
            'value' => $model->isExported->name,
        ],
    ],
    'buttons1' => '{update}',
])
?>
```

Why does the widget didn't save the edited data? What's wrong with my code?

### UPDATE:

This is the action in my controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productId]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I use the pure action, I didn't change the code in Controller.

#### this is my model

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\vatout\models;

use Yii;

class VatoutFakturOut extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'vatout_faktur_out';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'parent_id', 'product'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'parent_id', 'is_exported'], 'integer'],
        [['distDate', 'updated_at', 'created_at'], 'safe'],
        [['updated_by', 'created_by'], 'string', 'max' => 16],
        [['product'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
        ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'producrID' => 'Product ID',
        'user_id' => 'User ID',
        'parent_id' => 'Parent ID',
        'distDate' => 'Dist Date',
        'Product' => 'Product',
        'is_exported' => 'Is Exported',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIsExported()
{
    return $this->hasOne(VatoutStatus::className(), ['id' => 'is_exported']);
}
}
```

Comment: And what about your Controller that handles the request?

Comment: You should have notified me about the changes. I didn't notice that. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to notice you:(, my fault

Comment: I don't anything wrong. Can you provide your model?

Comment: Hi @EdvinTenovimas, the Model has been added. Please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line `$model = $this->findModel($id);`:

You're using `$this` on Controller, so it attempts to find a controller's data from database (which doesn't exist). Also, there is no such method `findModel()` in controller, this should be used on model that has `ActiveRecord` extension. The correct usage would be:

```
$model = VatoutFakturOut::findOne($id);
```

However, it seems that this widget does not pass any `$id` (therefore, parameter `$id` in `actionUpdate($id)` is useless). How to get the ID? From `Yii::$app->request->post()['VatoutFakturOut']['productId']`. But it should be checked if it's defined, otherwise you will get a warning:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();

if (empty($post['VatoutFakturOut']['productId'])) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not found.');
}
```

The 3rd thing is that you're giving the ability for user to edit the ID (even though it's not overwritten)... Which is something you shouldn't do. I would slightly change the code for view file:

```
'attributes' => [
    'product',
    [
        'attribute' => 'productId', 
        'options' => ['readonly' => true],
    ],
    'distDate',
    'created_at',
    'created_by',
    [
        'attribute' => 'is_exported',
        'value' => $model->isExported->name,
    ],
],
```

Assuming that `productId` is the primary key. This will not allow user to edit this field but it will still be sent to controller.

The final result:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    if (empty($post['VatoutFakturOut']['id'])) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('VatoutFakturOut not found.');
    }

    $model = VatoutFakturOut::findOne($post['VatoutFakturOut']['id']);

    if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productId]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```